# Removing item at pointer location from memory c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I've had to create a linked list type structure that takes advantage of STL. In there is a method that has to delete objects from this linked list structure. I currently have the method re-linking the table back up properly however I'm not confident that I'm actually deleting the object from memory correctly. I currently do the following:

```
myItem* item = current; //Current position and item to be deleted.

/* Code to move all elements around */

current = current->next; //Move current position along one in the list.

delete item;
```

My fear with that is that all I'm doing is creating a new pointer then deleting the pointer later once I've moved my current location instead of deleting the item itself.

I did a bit of googling and tried to add the command delete[] but then I get segmentation faults, I edited my code to look like:

```
myItem* item = current; //Current position and item to be deleted.

/* Code to move all elements around */

current = current->next; //Move current position along one in the list.

delete[] item; //Deletes item at memory location

delete item; //Deletes temporary pointer
```

If I keep it as per the top piece of code the program executes properly and does what it's supposed to do but I fear I'm not cleaning up my memory footprint properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is correct. A pointer is simply a memory address, and the value is copied into that local variable.

For example `current` is a `myItem*` pointer, and it may point to say, address 0XCDEF.
When you do an assignment such as `myItem* item = current`, that memory address is copied, so now `item` has the value 0XCDEF.

And so when you delete that pointer, that simply means your program is telling the operating system "Hey, I no longer need this space at 0XCDEF, please clean it up for me"

Comment: Happy days! Good to see I'm understanding correctly I just wanted to make sure that was how it worked. When you first start working with pointers things can get a little tricky. I'll accept this in 3 minutes! :D

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet is OK. When you do

```
delete item;
```

you delete the memory which the pointer points at, it makes no difference that the pointer is temporary. You can have many pointers pointing at the same place in memory, all they contain is the address to that memory. When you call `delete` on one of them, that memory is deleted and it does not matter which of the pointers you use, they all now point to deleted memory and should not be used.

The keyword `delete[]` is for deleting arrays, it tells C++ to look for the length of the array that starts at what the pointer points at and delete all the items in the array. In this case you should use `delete`, unless of course, the items in your link list are arrays.

Also, as haole noted, you should make sure the objects pointed to are created with the `new` keyword. Always pair `new` with `delete`, `new TYPE[]` with `delete[]` and, if you for some reason use the C counterparts in your code, `malloc()`/`calloc()` with `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

If current was created with "new", you are probably safe.

If you are unsure, use Valgrind. It is really handy, but you should try to learn your languange's concepts better.